# How does the map function know to isolate the adjusted column when calling its abbreviation (Ad)?

Tags: r, finance

I'm pulling price data from Yahoo Finance and am isolating the Adjusted Close prices from the data frame. The guide I'm following suggests using the map() function from the purrr package to pull this price column from the rest of the data with map(~Ad(get(.)))

I have three questions about this:
1. why is Ad preceded by a tilde?
2. how does the function know that the Adjusted Close column (which is titled as such) is associated with the abbreviation Ad?
3. what does the period do between the parentheses?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Answer to 1 and 3 is present in `?map`. Question 2 requires more context. `map(~Ad(get(.)))` isn't enough information for us to guess what's happening. Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Probably ``Ad` is a utility function for pulling the Adjusted Close column... have a look at `?Ad`. (I'd have a look too if you let us know what package(s) you're using.)